# can't get same results Matlab generates

Tags: c++, matlab, ode, odeint

Take a look at the following transfer function:

[image]

With Matlab Simulink:

[image]

The result is

[image]

In State-space representation, the system can be modeled as follows:

[image]

In Matlab, we can model the system in the state-space representation:

[image]

[image]

which yields the following plot:

[image]

which is exactly the result generated by using transfer function. I'm trying to generate same results with odeint but failed. This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

void equations(const state_type &y, state_type &dy, double x)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(3, 3), B(3,1);

    /*
        x = y[0]
       dx = y[1] = dy[0]
      ddx = y[2] = dy[1]
     dddx =        dy[2]

    */
    const double r(1);

    A <<   0,   1,  0,
           0,   0,  1,
         -24, -26, -9;

    B << 0, 0, 1;      
    //#####################( ODE Equations )################################
    Eigen::MatrixXd X(3, 1), dX(3,1);
    X << y[0], y[1], y[2];
    dX = A*X + B*r;

    dy[0] = dX(0,0);
    dy[1] = dX(1,0);
    dy[2] = dX(2,0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const double dt = 0.01;
    runge_kutta_dopri5 < state_type > stepper;

    state_type y(3); 
    // initial values
    y[0] = 0.0; //  x1 
    y[1] = 0.0; //  x2
    y[2] = 0.0; //  x3

    ofstream data("file.txt");

    for (double t(0.0); t <= 5.0; t += dt){
        data << t << " " << 2*y[0] << " " << 7*y[1] << " " << 1*y[2] << std::endl;
        stepper.do_step(equations, y, t, dt);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And this is the result for all state vector

[image]

None of the preceding variables match the results generated by Matlab. Any suggestions to fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the expression you have for y. When you multiply a 1x3 matrix with a 3x1 matrix, the result should be a 1x1 matrix, where the value of the single element is the dot product of the two matrices. What you're currently doing is element-wise multiplication when you write to `data` instead of calculating the dot product.

Comment: In your code where you're writing the results to data. Here you seem to be trying to compute Cx. (Going by the naming convention in the equations describing how the system can be modelled) Instead you're doing element-wise multiplication of C and x.

Comment: Oh man. What a careless mistake. Thank you. this is correct. now I can sleep.